Power of multiplication of powers
I have an issue where I want to compute ((-1 + a^2)^2  (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4) which should evaluate to Sqrt[(1 - a^2) (1 - b^2)] if both a and b are real and between 0 and 1.
First I tried the simple case, with only a
Simplify[((-1 + a^2)^2 )^(1/4), {Element[a, Reals], Abs[a] <= 1}]

It works, it gives Sqrt[1-a^2].
But when I try
Simplify[((-1 + a^2)^2  (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4), {Element[a, Reals],
 Abs[a] <= 1, Element[b, Reals], Abs[b] <= 1}]

I get my original expression back: ((-1 + a^2)^2  (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4)
What am I overlooking here?

Your desired result is not equivalent, e.g., try using ReplaceAll[expression, {a->-1/2, b->1/2}] on both the original and desired expressions.

For these types of things, it is better to use PowerExpand as it is designed for this.
PowerExpand[((-1 + a^2)^2)^(1/4)]


e=((-1+a^2)^2  (-1+b^2)^2)^(1/4)
PowerExpand[e]


Simplify and FullSimplify seem to be limited in handling power expanding of expressions and leave that task for specialized PowerExpand to handle. We see this from the following
 e2=((-1+a^2)^2  (-1+b^2)^2)^(1/4)


 assume=Reduce[e2==Sqrt[1-a^2]*Sqrt[1-b^2],Reals]


 FullSimplify[e2,Assumptions->assume]



To address your question, let us look at the number of leaves in both expressions:
LeafCount[((-1 + a^2)^2   (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4)]
LeafCount[Sqrt[(-1 + a^2) (-1 + b^2)]]

(* 19

15  *)

It means that the second expression should be the result. But it is not. In such a case, one should help Mathematica. One can do it in different ways.  @Nasser proposed one good way in his answer. You can also try to play with the ComplexityFunction:
g[e_] := Count[e, Rational[1, 4], Infinity];

Simplify[((-1 + a^2)^2   (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4), {Element[a, Reals], 
  Abs[a] <= 1, Element[b, Reals], Abs[b] <= 1}, 
 ComplexityFunction -> g]

(*  Sqrt[(-1 + a^2) (-1 + b^2)]  *)

or with replacements:
((-1 + a^2)^2 (-1 + b^2)^2)^(1/4) /. (u_^2*v_^2)^(1/4) :> (u*v)^(1/2)

(* Sqrt[(-1 + a^2) (-1 + b^2)]  *)

I guess there are still other possibilities that did not come into my head immediately.
Have fun!
